# Having trouble calling RxJS share using the recommended operator import

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-lettable-operators

I'm trying to understand the best practice for importing rxjs operators

It seems like I should import `share` this way, but, the following doesn't work because it says share expects 0 arguments.  I'm not quite sure how to call `share` correctly.

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

public currentUser: Observable<User> = share(this.currentUser$.asObservable());
```

Doing it the old way causes no problems.  However I seemed to have read that's not the preferred way to import https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/operator-imports.html

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

...

public currentUser: Observable<User> = this.currentUser$.asObservable().share();
```

How should I call share if I'm using the recommended way of importing?

Comment: Note that there also exists a [shareReplay](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html) operator that possibly is more useful and what you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Using `share` is like any other "pipable" operator since RxJS 5.5:

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

this.currentUser$.pipe(share());
```

For more details about pipable operators see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

However be aware that importing from `rxjs/operators` imports this entire file https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/index.ts.
This means that **if you bundle your app yourself** it might grow in size significantly.

So you might want to import each operator from it's own file like:

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/share';
```

... and then use it the same way.

This isn't always necessary. If you're using a preconfigured build system like `angular-cli` it does path mappings for you so you don't need to worry about it and always use `rxjs/operators`. You can read more about this:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3018
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking

Answer (score 0):

In RxJs 5.5 onwards, RxJs introduce Pipeable (or lettable) operators. Read in details here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

In short, using the below way is good in Rxjs 5.5 especially if you are using typescript.

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: so I tried importing the share like the suggestion but can't seem to figure out how to call `share` as in the example since it expects 0 arguments.

Comment: Just this line will work.

    `public currentUser: Observable<User> = this.currentUser$.asObservable().share();`

you dont need to import anything

Comment: because `.share()` after `asObservable()` is coming together, you don't need to import anything to do so.

Comment: the usage of pipeable operators are using during piping. for example,
`this.someStream$.pipe(share(....), switchMap(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first way of importing `import { share } from 'rxjs/operators'` is wrong because that is just importing the `share` operator class not the method operator.

In the second example `import 'rxjs/add/operator/share'` this is correct because it is saying I would like to add the `share` operator to my observable.

There's also `letable` operators in rxjs 5.5 like Chybie says but for your use case number 2 is correct.